# Create associations in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my form I have a select of a `type_control_access` in which I have three options, which the user chooses an option I want to save in a column in a table called `control_accesses`.

my model `type_control_access`:

```
class TypeControlAccess < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :control_accesses

  WORKSHOPS = 1
  CONFERENCES = 2
  PAPERS = 3

end
```

my model `control_access`:

```
class ControlAccess < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :type_control_access

end
```

but I already have an existing table:

```
class CreateControlAccesses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :control_accesses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I want to save the id of the `type_control_access` in `type_control_access_id` my `control_access` but with the rails associations, how can I do this?

I want something like this:

```
name: "antenna1", description: "this antenna is installed on the door", type_control_access_id: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand your request, you should create new migration to add new reference field between tables:

Sample in your terminal:

```
rails g migration AddTypeControlAccessToCreateControlAccesses TypeControlAccess:references
```

after that rub `rails db:migrate` and that would work.

Comment: what generates me?

Comment: it will add new column type_control_access_id to your table CreateControlAccesses thats the place where you will save association between tables, which you are missing now..

Comment: the command gives me an error: Mysql2::Error: Table 'RegistroAsistentes2_development.create_antenna_installeds' doesn't exist, Would not it be without the create?

Comment: thanks for the help, your command helped me for what I wanted, but it throws me some errors, investigating a bit I think it would be this way rails g migration add_type_control_accesses_to_control_accesses type_control_access:references

Comment: and then the migrate

Comment: yes, the best thing is for you to investigate more about the proposed solution, u however you can write the migration like that but it is also okay to use table names and camelcase

Comment: Of course, it works the same but the way I show you is the one that worked for me, thanks for your help!